# How do I Install Adobe Flex 3.6 Data Visualization Components for Flex Builder 3 on a Mac?

Tags: apache-flex, data-visualization

I just updated my Flex Builder 3 SDK to 3.6. I'm on a Mac.

Now, I'm trying to install the 3.6 Data Visualization Components. The link is found here: [www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk).

Adobe refers you to the release notes [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_sdk.html) for instructions on how to install the Components. Unfortunately, I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. I unzipped the file. I made a directory called 3.0 as a sub-directory of sdks. I put the data visualization components in  Adobe Flex Builder 3/sdks/3.0/data_visualization_sdk3.6.

a) What do I need to do next?

b) I don't have anything in the 3.0 directory. Should I have put the data_visualization_sdk3.6 folder in sdks/3.**6** instead?

c) After I get it set-up , how do import or load samples/explorer?

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the folder you put them into doesn't matter.

The Data Visualization Components are just a Flex library; so all you need to do to use it in a Flex project is to add the SWC to the library path.

The instructions your reading are for combining the data visualization package with the Flex 3.5 SDK. You don't need to do that to use them.

As far as I knew, there are no samples to load or import related to this.  But, if you [Google around](http://www.google.com/search?q=Adobe%20Data%20Visulaization%20samples&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=EWl&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sa=X&ei=KtTBTd69AejX0QHonI23Cg&ved=0CCkQvwUoAQ&q=Adobe%20Data%20Visualization%20examples&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c9365e657b732f11) or look at the [Adobe documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/datavis_flex3.pdf&rct=j&q=Adobe%20Data%20Visulaization%20documentation&ei=DNTBTcjwHIL50gHB8Km3Cg&usg=AFQjCNGpY07vzJ81tmvqgVFbz0cuCMJVOw&cad=rja) you may find some.

Comment: Thank you www.Flextras.com. I'll dump them in the library.